# Loop closes unexpectedly

Tags: c, loops

I checked this but it didn't help - [For loop scans one less time in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290067/for-loop-scans-one-less-time-in-c)
So, I'm new to programming and I was trying to solve this question from SPOJ (my doubt is general and hence didn't post it in SPOJ forums).
http://www.spoj.com/problems/STRHH
I made and ran this code in CodeBlocks using GCC where it runs as intended but runs differently when I ran it through Ideone.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,length,j;
    char **ptrarray; //creating a pointer array that holds addresses of the strings  
    fscanf(stdin,"%d",&n);
    ptrarray = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int)); //dynamically allocating memory for 'n' strings and storing their addresses in 'ptrarray'
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
        ptrarray[i] = (char *)malloc(201); //dynamically allocating memory for the strings
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
        fgets(ptrarray[i],201,stdin); //receiving string
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        length=strlen(ptrarray[i])-1; //string length
        for (j=0;j<(length)/2;j+=2) //obtain every other character up to half of the string length
            printf("%c",ptrarray[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
4
your 
progress 
is 
noticeable
```

Expected Output:

```
y
po
i
ntc
```

So, I get the expected output when I run it in Codeblocks but when running it on ideone (and submitting it on SPOJ), the printf loop only runs thrice instead of 4 times and the output I get is:

```
y
po
i
```

My question is why I'm not getting the fourth "ntc" in ideone and why is it not being accepted?

Edit: Changed "200" to "201" bytes, used fscanf instead of scanf, removed fflush and updated loop condition.
So, I get the required answer if I change loop condition from '

Comment: Calling `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior. Don't do that.

Comment: A string of 200 characters require 201 char storage (one extra for the string terminator).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, don;t see anything wrong there: fgets reads "_until the number of characters read is equal to_ `n - 1`",

Comment: I get confused by `char **ptrarray;` vs `ptrarray = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int))`.

Comment: `length=strlen(ptrarray[i])-1; //half of the string` I am sure that it's not the half length of the string

Comment: @unwind so what should be used instead? If I remove it completely then the scanf loop runs only thrice!

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks! Edited. The comments were incorrect, I have put the division factor in the loop instead.

Comment: Could someone suggest edited code that would give all 4 as output instead?

Comment: So, I get the required answer if I change loop condition from "<n" to "<=n". However doesn't this mean that it now runs 5 times instead of 4? Could someone please explain why this was necessary and what the 5th iteration of the loop does?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The problem description specifies lines of up to 200 characters. The code can only handle 199.

Comment: http://rextester.com/ZVD8795 <= solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
char **ptrarray; //creating a pointer array that holds addresses of the strings  
scanf("%d",&n);
ptrarray = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int)); //dynamically allocating memory for 'n' strings and storing their addresses in 'ptrarray'
```

Makes no sense; you're allocating space for `n` integers, but assigning the result to a pointer to a pointer (neither of which is the same size as an integer, in general).

The allocation should be:

```
ptrarray = malloc(n * sizeof *ptrarray);
```

This will allocate `n` times the size of whatever `ptrarray` points at, i.e. `sizeof (char *)`, but without repeating any type names.

This is a quite general and much safer pattern, worth learning.

As mentioned in the comment, don't `fflush(stdin);`, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Additional note, `ptrarray` is not an array, should be rename with a proper name.

Comment: @unwind sizeof *ptrarray is equivalent to sizeof char * right? And char * is a pointer to a character. So it will hold an unsigned integer. By that logic, isn't sizeof(int) the same as sizeof(char *) and by extension sizeof(*ptrarray)?

Comment: @NaishadhVora "And char * is a pointer to a character. So it will hold an unsigned integer." --> No.  Pointer sizes and `int` size are not correlated.

Comment: @chux I was given to understand that char * would hold the address of a character. Wouldn't that be in the form of a unsigned integer? Sorry, I'm pretty new at this!

Comment: @NaishadhVora "char * would hold the address of a character" Yes that is true.  "Wouldn't that be in the form of a unsigned integer?"  Maybe, maybe not - it is an implementation detail.  More importantly: code should not care about that.

Comment: @chux Oh now I get it! Thanks! But changing sizeof(int) to sizeof(*ptrarray) still only gives the 3 output. What needs to be changed to get "ntc" as well?

Comment: @NaishadhVora Hint: What causes `scanf("%d",&n);` to stop taking input?   `fgets()` then reads from that character.  Moral of the story - avoid `scanf()`.

Comment: @chux I used fscanf(stdin,"%d",&n); instead but it didn't help. The fgets() loops still only runs thrice. What would you suggest should be used? And the output still doesn't show "ntc"

Comment: So, I get the required answer if I change loop condition from "<n" to "<=n". However doesn't this mean that it now runs 5 times instead of 4? Could someone please explain why this was necessary and what the 5th iteration of the loop does?

Comment: @NaishadhVora "why this was necessary"  is answered by the question you avoided: "What causes scanf("%d",&n); to stop taking input?"  The `'\n'` is not consumed.

Comment: @chux Got it! Thanks! Also, is there any way to prevent fgets() from taking '\n' as input?

Comment: @chux Got it! Thanks! Also, is there any way to prevent fgets() from using '\n' as input?

Comment: The point of `fgets()` is to read up to  and including `'\n'`.

Comment: The dirty solution is to `scanf("%d%*c",&n);` to consume the character after the number (hopefully `'\n'`).  The robust solution: `char b[80]; fget(b, sizeof b, stdin); sscanf(b, "%d%*c",&n);`  with some error checking.